# MySQL Select from multiple tables WHERE compare is NULL gives values from previous rows

Tags: mysql, select, null

I'm trying to get a list of all rows of Table B and, if given, the matching name from Table A. but my result is not as wanted :/

would be nice if you could help :)

Here's the (stripped down) code:

Table A:

```
ID | Name | …
1 | foo | …
2 | bar | …
3 | baz | …
```

Table B:

```
ID | A_ID | …
1 | 1 | …
2 | 3 | …
3 | 2 | …
4 | 1 | …
5 | NULL | …
```

My Query:

```
SELECT B.ID, A.Name FROM A, B WHERE B.A_ID = A.ID OR B.A_ID IS NULL ORDER BY B.ID ASC
```

My desired Output would be something like this:

```
1 | foo
2 | baz
3 | bar
4 | foo
5 | NULL or ''
```

but it is:

```
1 | foo
2 | baz
3 | bar
4 | foo
5 | foo <-- huh?
```

thanks a lot!

Edit: okay the LEFT JOIN thing works for simple setups, but in my real query im getting stuff from 5 tables and it looks I cant pass 2 tables into a JOIN - or I'm simply too dump :(

```
SELECT 
c.name as c_name, 
a.name as a_name,
p.name as p_name,
e.memo
FROM 
e, c, x, a, p
WHERE 
e.id = x.e_id AND c.id = x.c_id
AND a.id = e.a_id
AND (p.id = e.p_id OR e.p_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: Do an explicit `OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  For one thing, you would then learn about `LEFT JOIN`, which is what you want:

```
SELECT B.ID, A.Name
FROM B LEFT JOIN
     A 
     ON B.A_ID = A.ID 
ORDER BY B.ID ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a `LEFT JOIN` is what you want here

```
 SELECT 
  B.ID, 
  A.NAME /* Will be null if A record doesn't exist */
 FROM B 
 LEFT JOIN A ON B.A_ID = A.ID
 ORDER BY B.ID ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd use a left join if you dont want to find all matches in the table previous, then you dont specify that you want to find nulls in the where, because that would find only nulls.

```
SELECT B.ID, A.Name FROM A
LEFT JOIN B 
ON B.A_ID = A.ID 
ORDER BY B.ID ASC
```